# Python: How to get two integers out of one object in a list

Tags: python, list, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a circle detection program which will after detection control/test if the circle is really there. I am trying to do that with putting x and y of circle in a list once-this is the control list. The object list is every x and y of the circle continuously put in, not only once. Then it will count/compare with the control list `ObjectList.count(ControlList[i])` how many times the x and y has appeared in the object list. And if it appeared more than 5 times it draws it.

My question is how to get x and y from this:

`['46,101', '91,86', '46,100', '137,64', '54,53', '99,31', '91,85', '91,87']`

The first one is x and the second one is y

```
    if pregled == 0:  # Checks if ControlList was wiped clear after 10 checks

            if count < 11: # counts to 10 the sets pregled = 1
                    count = count + 1

                    for cnt1 in contours1:

                            #ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt,cnt1,1,0.0)

                            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt1)

                            if area > 500:

                                  ret = cv2.matchShapes(cnt,cnt1,1,0.0)

                                  if ret < 0.02:


                                          if len(cnt1) > 0:
                                                  M = cv2.moments(cnt1)

                                                  if M["m00"] != 0:

                                                          cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
                                                          cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

                                                          #Conturji = '('+str(cx)+','+str(cy)+')'
                                                          Conturji = str(cx) +','+ str(cy) # Puts everything in string

                                                          if Conturji not in ControlList: # Checks if it already is in ControlList

                                                                  ControlList.append(Conturji)

                                                          print(ControlList)
```

`

Comment: Why do you put it in that format in the first place? Why not use a list or tuple of two ints instead of putting it in a string?

Comment: use tuples instead of cramming both coords into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x_y= ['46,101', '91,86', '46,100', '137,64', '54,53', '99,31', '91,85', '91,87']
new_list = [value.split(",") for value in x_y]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['46', '101'], ['91', '86'], ['46', '100'], ['137', '64'], ['54',
'53'], ['99', '31'], ['91', '85'], ['91', '87']]
```

So you have a list of 2 element lists you can cast it to Tuple or any other object.

If you want to just pick one element and unpack it then you can do it like this:

```
x,y = x_y[0].split(",")
```

However it would be far more efficient if you would changed this line:

`Conturji = str(cx) +','+ str(cy)`

To

`Conturji = (cx,cy)`

Tuples are fast and efficient and later on you can even print them right away:

```
tuple = (1,2)
print(tuple)
```

`(1,2)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But when i want to draw a circle with the center in x and y it says that it must be integer not a touple. @Sayse @U9-Forward 

`for p in ControlList:
       cv2.circle(img_crop, ControlList[p], 5, (0, 255, 0),-1)`

Comment: you can unpack a tuple or access just one argument either `*ControlList[p]` unpacks it to two values or `ControlList[p][0]` for `x` or `ControlList[p][1]` for `y`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function

```
a = ['46,101', '91,86', '46,100', '137,64', '54,53', '99,31', '91,85', '91,87']


x = list(i.split(',')[0] for i in a)
y = list(i.split(',')[1] for i in a)
print(x) #['46', '91', '46', '137', '54', '99', '91', '91']
print(y) #['101', '86', '100', '64', '53', '31', '85', '87']
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is never put them in as a string in the first place, you should have your loop add them to the list as a tuple to save having to ever post process it to get your actual output

```
Conturji = str(cx) +','+ str(cy) # Puts everything in string
```

should be

```
Conturji = cx, cy
```

Your output would then become

```
[ (46, 101), (91, 86), (46,100), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`map`:

```
x_y= ['46,101', '91,86', '46,100', '137,64', '54,53', '99,31', '91,85', '91,87']
new_list = list(map(lambda x: x.split(','),x_y))
print(new_list)
```

Or:

```
x,y= list(map(lambda x: x.split(','),x_y))
print(x)
print(y)
```

But still the best way would be:

Replace:

```
Conturji = str(cx) +','+ str(cy) # Puts everything in string
```

With:

```
Conturji = cx,cy
```